# Копирование всего кода страницы сайта на C#

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть такая штука парс сайта.. берем сайт, определенную страницу, определенный блок.. спарсили. т.е. задача в большинстве случаев решается применением чьего ни будь кода, который расковаривает 0,0001% от кода страницы (пусть и самого нужного). Наткнулся на неоднократное применение сторонних решений.

Может ли кто подсказать как скопировать весь код определенной страницы в переменную? Да да весь, без посторонних решений, без классов и прочей хрени. В итоге должна получиться переменная, у которой внутри записано то, что обычно можно увидеть нажав на страницы сайта клавиши 'ctrl+u'

p.s. извращение конечно..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто, используйте класс [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string pageMarkup = null;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    pageMarkup = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: эмм.. @Shad - это оно самое! Решение принимаю, если не сложно прошу в решении дописать кое что, что бы все пользовались. Сейчас только с кодировкой справлюсь и все

    MessageBox.Show(pageMarkup);