# Зайти на сайт через прокси

Tags: c#, proxy

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Давным давно была такая тема заходить на сайт через прокси. У кого для скорости, у кого для секретности. Использовался ест-но браузер. Можно ли так на с# ? Может ли кто кодом показать как это делать?

[Меня тут недавно научили желанному](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/291058/) - простой пример как получить исходный код сайта. Вот думаю как к этому решению прикрутить прокси или 'много прокси'

p.s. про данную тему нигде никак (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `WebClient'a` есть свойство [Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.proxy(v=vs.100).asp). Ну а его задание выглядит примерно так:

```
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("адрес прокси");
```

Если прокси с авторизацией по логину/паролю, то можно так:

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("адрес прокси");
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("логин", "пароль");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = proxy;
```

Comment: Что бы client.Proxy понимал - нужно подключить что то по using ?? Что то до меня ответ не дошел. C using играть уже пробовал, знаний по этому вопросу у меня явно не достает. Может кто помочь?

Comment: @mixalef а в чем проблема-то? У класса **WebClient** есть свойство [**Proxy**][1], возвращающее экземпляр IWebProxy. Этот тип определён в System.Net, как и WebClient.  Это свойство не является методом расширения, следовательно никаких дополнительных using писать не требуется

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Пробовал так, видимо это не весь код который нужно использовать:

    namespace MyTestingProga{
        public partial class Form1 : Form{
            public Form1(){
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            client.Proxy = new WebProxy("myProxyIp");
        }
    }

Comment: @mixalef, потому что строчку 

client.Proxy = new WebProxy("myProxyIp");

нужно помещать в функцию.

Comment: @mixalef будьте внимательнее - у вас код синтаксически некорректен

Comment: синтаксис сейчас исправляю. может кто полным кодом удивить? А то как писать неправильно теперь знаю, как правильно нет, хотя хочу научиться

Comment: @mixalef на MSDN есть примеры